# Taxonomy view : add token term_name in url

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, panels, tokens

I have a view overriding taxonomy term pages with the help of Panels. I defined that pattern in URL aliases : `destinations/[term:parents]/[term:name]`.

Now I'd like to set a clone of that view, slightly different in its filters, **with the same panelizer variant** (or a variant clone), following URL pattern :`destinations/[term:parents]/[term:name]/foo` where foo is a fixed word.

How could I do that please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what expected.

**In the content pane view**, Contextual filters : Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth), use the filter value type "*Term name converted to term ID*"

[image: filter value type "Term name converted to term ID"]

**In the custom page**, in basics, set the path almost as in the question `destinations/[term:name]/foo` (I abandoned the `[term:parents]` part, no way).

And in arguments, choose "*argument type:term name*".